# Which REST method to use if only sending path variable and key-value pair in header to trigger business logic?

Tags: java, httprequest, spring-rest

I'm working on a web-game for training purposes. In this project I'm using Spring-Boot and REST endpoints to execute CRUD operations and trigger business logic methods. 
One endpoint of mine looks like this:

```
@PatchMapping("companies/{companyId}/upgrade-star-value")
    @ResponseBody
    public String upgradeStarValue(@PathVariable int companyId, @RequestHeader(name = "playerId") int playerId)
            throws GameLogicException {
        return companyBusinessLogicService.upgradeStarValue(playerId, companyId);
    }
```

The purpose of this endpoint is to trigger a method that validates the amount of specific resources of the player with the passed `playerId` and then reduces them and upgrades the star value of the company with the passed `companyId`. So everything is done without a request body.

Know I was wondering which REST method I should use to accomplish that. Should I use `POST` or `PATCH` or is there another method for the case that no request body but path variable and request header is sent? Is there a best practice to deal with such a case?

I tried to look up other posts, but it's hard for me to briefly express my problem in a google search, so the results don't apply to my problem. Therefore I am happy about hints to other posts.

Comment: Choosing method is not based on how body looks alike but on the outcome of operation.

Comment: @Antoniossss How would you characterize my outcome in my use case if I only response with a simple string that informs about the success of the upgrade? FYI the string varies depending on the star level.

Comment: The most importatnt question is if your operation is idempotent. If so - use PUT, if not, POST would be more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that your operation is **not idempotent**. In such case POST will suit your needs and will be more or less RESTful.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case you can use PUT but this is a link that can help you to understand which method used for [Click](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Comment: On the page you linked to it's written that the PUT call is idempotent. In my use case I can upgrade a star value four times and every time it will be counted one up ==> from 1->2, 2->3, 3->4 and 4->5. That doesn't count as idempotent anymore, does it? So should I use POST instead? I have still bit trouble understanding idempotent for 100%.